# How to add values in hashmap with the same key and when value is stored as another hashmap

Tags: collections, java-8, maps

I have a list of maps and I want to add values if the keys are equal. Values also stored as map. As output I want a single map as in example below.

I expect the output of

```
[
    {user1={service1=10.24, service2=0.11, service3=18.76}}, 
    {user1={service1=200.25, service2=0.05, service4=0.00}}
    {user2={service1=50.25, service4=0.05, service5=0.00}}
]
```

to be

```
{
    user1={service1=210.49, service2=0.16, service3=18.76, service4=0.00},
    user2={service1=50.25, service4=0.05, service6=0.00}
}
```

Comment: What does the declaration of your variable look like? ```List<Map<String, Map<String, Double>>>```?

Comment: Don’t define a task by a textual output.

Answer (score 2):

it's a combination of different collectors:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map = list.stream()
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.flatMapping(m -> m.getValue().entrySet().stream(),
                    Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Double::sum))));
```

Example:

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, Double>>> list = List.of(
         Map.of("user1", Map.of("service1", 10.24, "service2", 0.11, "service3", 18.76)),
         Map.of("user1", Map.of("service1", 200.25, "service2", 0.05, "service3", 0.0)),
         Map.of("user2", Map.of("service1", 50.25, "service2", 0.05, "service3", 0.0))
);
```

will produce

```
{
 user1={service2=0.16, service1=210.49, service3=18.76}, 
 user2={service2=0.05, service1=50.25, service3=0.0}
}
```